# Shell script to automate realm export from Keycloak container (force exit container)

Tags: shell, docker, keycloak

I'm trying to create a script to automate the process of exporting a realm from a Keycloack docker container.

The problem is that standalone.sh seems to require an interactive terminal and I need to stop it with CTRL+C for the docker cp command to work, this is a problem when want to run this from Jenkins.

I am not able to run any other commands after standalone.sh stops. How can I send a kill signal after the export commands have finished?

```sh
export_realm.sh

#!/bin/sh

echo "Starting export process";

docker exec -it keycloak keycloak/bin/standalone.sh \
-Dkeycloak.migration.action=export \
-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 \
-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile \
-Dkeycloak.migration.realmName=myRealm \
-Dkeycloak.migration.usersExportStrategy=SKIP \
-Dkeycloak.migration.file=/tmp/realm_export.json 

# I need to exit here (Ctrl + C)

docker cp keycloak:/tmp/realm_export.json ./test.json

echo "Export finished, file copied to host";
```

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: No, not yet unfortunately

Comment: This has been solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60972882/892914

Comment: I did not test this myself, but it looks like the link you provided should solve the problem.

We upgraded to the new quarkus based version of Keycloak and now use postgres database for persistence, so this issue is not really relevant for us anymore.